# Datagridview doesn't clear or replace the previos data vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Can't find the way to replace the previous data with the new one....

I use a button to view my table in dgv. When I click the button twice for viewing my table it only show the data next with the previous one

Here's the code that I'm using

```
Private Sub cmdview_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdview.Click

    connetionstring = "Integrated Security = SSPI; data source= DELL-PC;Initial catalog=Library System"
    connection = New SqlConnection(connetionstring)
    sql = "select * from dbo.tblbook"

    Try

        connection.Open()
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        connection.Close()
        dtg1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        Return
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx
"Tables and columns are only created if they do not already exist; otherwise Fill uses the existing DataSet schema. "
Meaning if you have data in your dataset it will not be overwritten if you use fill. So try this before your adapter.Fill line:

```
ds.Clear()
```

Comment: It works. Thank you for helping me. i will read this thanks a lot.